# How to check if rows copied to another sheet by VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook contains two sheets (Opened_Items & Closed_Items).
I have a macro to copy some rows from sheet (Opned_Items) to sheet (Closed_Items) based on certain condition.

Sometimes, because the workbook is shared, some rows are not copied.

How do I check by using VBA if data copied to sheet (Closed_Items)?

**Note**: Data in cells (C:E) is unique and can be used to check if data copied.

[image]

[image]

```vb
Sub Copy_to_Closed_Sheet()
   
Dim Close_Data As Range, Cell As Object

Set Close_Data = Worksheets("Opned_Items").Range("B3:B500")
For Each Cell In Close_Data
If Cell.value = "Close" Then
Cell.EntireRow.Copy

Worksheets("Closed_Items").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use Vlookup check for the result, do you really need VBA?

Comment: Consider an alternative setup: Keep only one sheet with a column which has values of TRUE or FALSE, meaning "Closed" or "Not closed". Users either select True/False from a validation drop-down or the value is set automatically "based on certain conditions". You display either closed or open positions by applying a filter. If you want to automate that, create a toggle button that calls a macro which applies one filter or the other. In this way, since there is no copying, there can't be copying errors.

Comment: 'Some rows not copied altogether' - Does that mean that some rows are not at all copied or only parts of the row are copied?

Comment: @Kin Siang. kindly could you help with VBA using Vlookup .

Comment: Can you add formula on your open_item for checking? Because it will become very easy to solve, I will based on your comment to think about the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking Missing Rows

I assume you want to see it listed in a different sheet.

Add a sheet named 'DeviationsSht' and run the following code.

```
Sub CheckDiscrepancy()
    
    Dim sourceRng As Range, fndRng As Range, destlRow As Long, destRng As Range, rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set sourceRng = Worksheets("Opened_Items").Range("B3", Worksheets("Opened_Items").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set fndRng = Worksheets("Closed_Items").Range("E3", Worksheets("Closed_Items").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    destlRow = Worksheets("DeviationsSht").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        With Worksheets("DeviationsSht").Range("A2", "F" & destlRow).Cells
        
            .Clear
            .UseStandardHeight = True
            .UseStandardWidth = True
        
        End With
    
        For Each rng In sourceRng
        
            If rng.Value = "Close" Then
            
                If fndRng.Find(What:=rng.Offset(0, 3).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
                    
                        rng.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("DeviationsSht").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        destlRow = Worksheets("DeviationsSht").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        
                        With Worksheets("DeviationsSht").Range("A2", "F" & destlRow)
                        
                            .WrapText = False
                            .Columns.AutoFit
                        
                        End With
                
                End If
            
            End If
        
        Next rng
    
End Sub
```

About copy paste not working for all rows, could you try the following code.

```
Sub Copy_to_Closed_Sheet()

    Dim sourceRng As Range, lastrow As Long, destRng As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set sourceRng = Worksheets("Opened_Items").Range("B3", Worksheets("Opened_Items").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    lastrow = Worksheets("Closed_Items").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    
    Worksheets("Closed_Items").Range("A3", "F" & lastrow).Cells.ClearContents
    
    
        For Each rng In sourceRng
        
            If rng.Value = "Close" Then
            
                Set destRng = Worksheets("Closed_Items").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                rng.EntireRow.Copy destRng
                
            End If
            
        Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: The first code (Sub CheckDiscrepancy) , it copied Rows with (Close) but paste same data many times on  Worksheets("DeviationsSht").

Comment: The Second code (Copy_to_Closed_Sheet) , the pasted data shifted cells in rows (1&2). even I modified  { Offset(1, 0) } to Offset(2, 0) , But the same problem

Comment: @Waleed_wwm It still works for me. In the second code (Copy_to_Closed_Sheet), there is no line that inserts or shifts cells down. By any chance, could you upload the file here with mock data, if the current data is confidential? About the first code, are you sure the data does not repeat in the sheet named 'Opened_Items'? If there is duplicate data in there, then it will repeat in the 'DeviationsSht'.

Comment: I found no way to upload file here , So I uploaded to this site    https://easyupload.io/c5o1sd

Comment: @Waleed_wwm The codes given above have been modified. Please copy the above code now and check. It should be working.

Comment: After update , The first code (Sub CheckDiscrepancy) works perfectly , But Second code (Copy_to_Closed_Sheet) new Data overwrite old data in (Closed_Items )

Comment: I deleted this line of Second code and all now works perfectly (    Worksheets("Closed_Items").Range("A3", "F" & lastrow).Cells.ClearContents ). Many Thanks "AvinEswar" for all your help

Comment: @Waleed_wwm That line is to prevent  repetition of data (that is why it overwrites). Otherwise the data in Opened_Items will get repeatedly posted in Closed_Items every time the code runs.